# Swapping two variables in Java without using a third variable or an API

Tags: java

I recently went to an interview and I was asked to write some code to swap the values of two variables without using third variable or any API.

I could not work out how to do this, can you help me on this?

For example I have two variable `a=10` and `b=20` the output should be `b=10` and `a=20`.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky but not that hard to figure out:

```
a = 10
b = 20

a = a + b; //a = 30, b = 20
b = a - b; //a = 30, b = 10 
a = a - b; //a = 20, b = 10
```

Comment: adding 10 and 20 causes overflow?

Comment: Do we have any algorithm to swap.Here we are going with values.Suppose if we have to read the values from the keyboard and the with the swapped output mean how to solve @Nima

Comment: If instead of 20 you use Integer.MAX_VALUE you will get overflow. However, I think it all comes out in the wash and the values should be correct at the end.

Comment: this doesn't work with strings.. use XOR algorithmn as mentioned above

Comment: @PiotrMiazga XOR swap won't work for String either.

Comment: @Nima then how in the case of String???